# Menu underline on hover, text length not element length

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, underline

I'm trying to have an underline bellow the menu items on hover that is the length of the word.
For now, it takes the length of the element.
How can I achieve this?

````
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand active" href="index.html">
        <img src="./examWebLaBotteLogo.svg" alt="Logo de LA BOTTE"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="menu.html">La carte</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="suggestions.html">Nos suggestions</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="event.html">Événements</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact & horaires</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>```


.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid#b40900;
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding from hover and add margin to normal class see the example and text decoration is none also. hope it will help ..

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin:5px;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:2rem;
    color: black;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #b40900;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand active" href="index.html">
        <img src="./examWebLaBotteLogo.svg" alt="Logo de LA BOTTE"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-between w-100">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="menu.html">La carte</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="suggestions.html">Nos suggestions</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="event.html">Événements</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact & horaires</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just tested the code you sent but it doesn't achieve the result.
see this codepen: https://codepen.io/Guillaume_dev/pen/LYpyEjO

Comment: @Tanuki  your are using bootstrap so remove the class nav-fill and use your custom class to give margin to anchor tags or you can replace the class nav-fill with justify-content-between ... it will work if not let me know

Comment: you are right, it is working with justify-content-between. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

Please note that I'm using Elementor Navigation Menu Widget

```
.hfe-nav-menu__layout-horizontal li.menu-item, .hfe-nav-menu__layout-horizontal > li.menu-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.elementor-21 .elementor-element.elementor-element-48d02c5 .menu-item a.hfe-menu-item {
     padding-left: 0px !important; 
     padding-right: 0px !important; 
}
```